# Compile vowpal-wabbit in ubuntu for use in windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, ubuntu, cygwin, vowpalwabbit

I have a `Windows 7` laptop with an `Ubuntu 12.04` installation on the same machine.

I am trying to compile a program from source (`VowPal Wabbit`).  I tried using `Cygwin` but had no luck getting it to work.  I ended up installing `Ubuntu 12.04` to get access to get a functioning compiler.

It worked on the `Ubuntu` side but I am curious if there is a way to bring the compiled files over to `Windows` as that's where I actually do most of my work.  More specifically, will programs compiled in `Ubuntu` function on a `Windows` machine?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/):

> MinGW, a contraction of "Minimalist GNU for Windows", is a minimalist
>   development environment for native Microsoft Windows applications.

Answer (score 1):

I realize it is almost a year later.  Credit Chris Quirk, Nick Nussbaum and others, current versions of vowpal wabbit (7.x) should build and work fine on Windows. 
[This reference](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/README.windows.txt) should provide all the necessary details.

**Edit: 2017-07-10:**
I should also note: the library and basic train and test from files functionality has been working on Windows for a while. However, not all the functionality supported in a native Linux environment is available on Windows. In particular, the `--daemon` option, network related features like spanning-tree (under the `cluster` directory), and some of the utilities under the `util` directory have not been fully ported and/or tested on Windows. `vw` developers welcome pull-requests from Windows users.